# How would I make a backend for my Electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, electron, backend

So I'm making an Electron app and I'm at the point of trying to incorporate security. Since Electron allows DevTools and can easily be unpacked I'm looking into a backend. I'm not really sure how I'm supposed to make the backend and access it without leaking auth tokens and other secrets. So my question is:

1. How would I make a backend that will work with Electron?
2. How would I conceal the auth token?

I don't really have any code to show so sorry about that. If you need anything clarified let me know.

Comment: anything on the client the client can own and have access to.

Comment: That's the problem. How do apps like Slack and Discord keep this info safe? How would I make a backend like that?

Comment: they dont - they just sign tokens and validate that the tokens match the signature - look up jwts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Due to an Electron App being basically a website packed into an App, I'd recommend using an API-based backend. Then you can use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) in javascript to exchange data with your backend.
2. Just do it like with any Web-App. Let the user sign-in, by posting to your API backend. Your backend then generates and returns a [cryptographically secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) [session token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID), which is then stored in localStorage of your electron frontend. The session token can then be used to access the users information on your backend server (via further API requests). So your server associates the session token with the user, so the user can prove his identity using the session token instead of sending his password to your server every time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29

Be vary that keys stored on any frontend can be extracted. Some make it easy, for example websites, some make it harder, for example desktop apps, but with enough patience, someone can eventually extract it.

When you have an API key which you don't want the client to have, let the client request your API backend, and then you request the other API with the key from your server. This way, the client never sees the key, because he requests the 3rd party API through your server. So only your server has that key. This way your server is able to control the requests to the third party API and even limit or ban users of your App if they are abusing your service.

[image]

Comment: So basically if I make a two API's I should be able to keep most everything safe? Also I'm not quite understanding session tokens. How do I make a session token and will this token be able to only see data for a specific user or will it be able to see it for everyone?

Comment: @SamuelCorsi-House the session token is user specific. Your server generates one (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) after a user logged himself in using name and password. The user uses his session token to prove his identity to your server (so he doesn't have to send his username and password with every request). And you only have one API, I was talking about 3rd party APIs where you don't want their key to be exposed to the client, for example a movie database API where you baught an API key and don't want the client to see that key.

Comment: So my backend will make the request using the paid API key and return the data to the client?

Comment: @SamuelCorsi-House yes, because you don't want one of your clients go playing with the API key you paid for. So your backend authenticates the user and then allows him under controlled circumstances to access the 3rd party API which you paid for through your API.

Answer (score 0):

As you've lead on, there potential security holes in Electron apps, namely around the use of **remote** and **nodeIntegration** allowing js code direct access to your OS. Other points of vulnerability come from the fact that since your app is all client side, really no code is safe.

The electron team publishes [a list](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security) of ways to secure your app. While I don't suggest this template solves *everything* you are looking for (I do agree you need a backend), this template (https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template) has all of the recommended security practices baked-in.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of this template*.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will take a look. :)